# Firefox blocks Cookies from self signed ssl

Tags: oracle, ssl, firefox, https

I configured my Oracle ORDS Standalone Server from http to use https with a auto ssl.
I think its a self signed ssl. When i accept in firefox this 'insecure' connection, the browser block my cookies from my page. In safari it works. How can i tell firefox to accept the cookies?
[image: allow certificate]
[image: Cookies blocked]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/995117

Comment: No, my browser accept the certificate now but block this coockies